# How to generate the word report from excel?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I want to convert the following excel content into a word document .
The new word report contains the student name ,date ,subject , original exam time and new exam time .
[image]
[image]

I tried to use a simple way to do this . Copy range(a79:L85) & range(A90:L92) to the new word document .But it doesn't work and joins the two table together (into same row ).

```
    Sub ExcelRangeToWord()

'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Table Into a New Word Document
'NOTE: Must have Word Object Library Active in Order to Run _
  (VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library)
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim tbl As Excel.RANGE
Dim tbl2 As Excel.RANGE
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordTable As Word.Table

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

'Copy Range from Excel
  Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet9.Name).RANGE("A79:L85") 'copy the name ,subject and old exam time 
  Set tbl2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet99.Name).RANGE("A90:L92")'copy the new exam time 
'Create an Instance of MS Word
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is MS Word already opened?
      Set WordApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
      If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  WordApp.Visible = True
  WordApp.Activate

'Create a New Document
  Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add


'Copy Excel Table Range
  tbl.Copy ' paste range1
  tbl2.Copy 'paste range2

'Paste Table into MS Word
  myDoc.Paragraphs(1).RANGE.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False

'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
  Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
  WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Any hints or methods can generate a word report like this ?

Comment: If you need the output and aren't doing this as an exercise, mail merge would be simpler and would also execute much faster.

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi But I have to calculate the new time using excel .And the individual document must be word . Mail merge can perform this ? Any reference link?

Answer (score 0):

This could be only a part of the solution explaining of how to copy+paste tables one after another.

```
'....
'Trigger copy separately for each table + paste for each table

    tbl.Copy ' paste range1
    myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=False, _
        RTF:=False

'before that...
'...go to end of doc and add new paragraph
    myDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    tbl2.Copy 'paste range2

'Paste Table into MS Word last paragraph
    myDoc.Paragraphs(myDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=False, _
        RTF:=False
```

Comment: Using your code ,it will produce two different table .The format will be inconsistency (columns are not in same format).Also , some word size make it become 2 rows. Lastly , it cannot inherit the font-position (center) from the original excel file . How to improve it ?

Comment: It is better to make it into 1 table . And it is better inherit the format from the original excel file .Also , the cell space should fit the word length .Any idea to fix it ?

Comment: You should make more effort to prepare better layout in excel file. Next, you could try with another Pasting option, something like Paste or PasteSpecial. You could try to record macro in Word only with pasting solution which is best for you.